# Allocate AWS SSO Permission Set to Groups in Accounts

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-sso

Working to fully code the aws sso set up

So far coded via Terraform I have all permission-sets and using scim to pull in groups.
Allocation of the permission sets to groups in accounts (I have over 100 accounts) is done by hand. I want to allocate permission sets to groups in selected accounts via IaC (Terraform) but I cant for the life of me find working code.

Ive tried using

`aws_sso_permission_set_group_assignment`,
`aws_sso_permission_set_group_attachment`,
`aws_sso_group_permission_set_assignment`,
`aws_sso_group_permission_set_attachment`,
`aws_sso_permission_set_attachment`,
`aws_sso_permission_set_assignment`,

These i found in some old docs but they dont work :( giving `The provider hashicorp/aws does not support resource type`

Does anyone have any advice they can offer of how to remedy this or how they managed to surmount this issue

Here is example of code tried

```
resource "aws_sso_group_permission_set_attachment" "example" {
     group_id          = "93sd433ee-cd43e4b-cfww-434e-re33-707a0987eb"
     permission_set_id = "arn:aws:sso:::permissionSet/ssoins-63456a11we432d8/ps-1231ded3d42fcrr2"
     account_id = "8765322052550"
}

resource "aws_sso_group_permission_set_attachment" "example" {
     permission_set_arn = "arn:aws:sso:::permissionSet/ssoins-63456a11we432d8/ps-1231ded3d42fcrr2"
     group_name = "93sd433ee-cd43e4b-cfww-434e-re33-707a0987eb"
     account_id = "8765322052550"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ssoadmin_account_assignment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ssoadmin_account_assignment) resource is something which you **might** be looking for, please go through all the available attributes in the resource to match your needs.

```
resource "aws_ssoadmin_account_assignment" "example" {
  instance_arn       = tolist(data.aws_ssoadmin_instances.example.arns)[0]
  permission_set_arn = "arn_of_the_permission_set" # replace this with actually permission set arn 

  principal_id   = "group_id" # replace this with groupID 
  principal_type = "GROUP"

  target_id   = "012347678910" # replace with account ID 
  target_type = "AWS_ACCOUNT" 
}
```

Comment: You my friend are a life saver